# Use Facebook Comments without posting back to Facebook?

Tags: facebook-comments

I would like to use Facebook Comments with my blog software as there is integration. However, I only want to use it since most people already have Facebook and we won't be allowing registrations (And we don't want a bunch of anon comments).

Can we set it up so that people can comment, but those comments only display on the blog and don't end up being posted to users timelines or anywhere else on Facebook?

I know about the 'Post to Facebook' option, but I want to make sure that is turned off as well so users don't have the choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to documentation, there is no option to disable it. You can use another comment system with facebook connect, as well as other login options. Try e.g. http://disqus.com

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/